# How can I animate coordinate data in gnuplot?

Tags: animation, gnuplot

I have 4 sets of coordinate data (2D, let's say it represents a square at different positions). How can I animate their positions in gnuplot (please recommend if other programs are easier to achieve this) so that it looks like it is rotating counter-clockwise?

Position 1:

`1 1
3 1
3 3
1 3`

Position 2:

`-1 1
-3 1
-3 3
-1 3`

Position 3:

`-1 -1
-3 -1
-3 -3
-1 -3`

Position 4:

`1 -1
3 -1
3 -3
1 -3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't write whether you want a filled square or lines or animated `gif` or something else. 
You can start with something like this. Make sure that the data is separated by two empty lines, such that gnuplot will recognize the blocks which you can address via `index i`.
Also check `help gif`.

**Code:**

```
### animation of square
reset session
set size square 

$Data <<EOD
# Position 1:
1 1
3 1
3 3
1 3


# Position 2:
-1 1
-3 1
-3 3
-1 3


# Position 3:
-1 -1
-3 -1
-3 -3
-1 -3


# Position 4:
1 -1
3 -1
3 -3
1 -3
EOD

set xrange [-4:4]
set yrange [-4:4]

set term gif animate delay 100 optimize
set output "tbAnimationSquare.gif"
do for [i=0:3] {
    plot $Data u 1:2 index i w filledcurves lc rgb "red" not
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @theozh. It definitely solves my problem